# Prevent adding to cart a product in "non multiple" qty when qty Increments enabled

Tags: cart, addtocart, quantity, multiple

Is there any easy way to show a warning in the product page and prevent adding product to cart instead of showing the message in cart page, when the quantity increments entered in quantity input field are incorrect?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a block that would be called before_body_end based on events responsible for product listing and product view.

In that block you could generate data for template file in which you'd loop over the data and generate JavaScript array of minimum/maximum/increment quantities.

Then create a JS function that will prevent submission of the product view form/product list button unless the min/max/inc quantities are correct in the quantity input. Input quantities would need to be specified with a product-id so you can find associated value in JS array easily.

If you don't understand something or have a problem with specific fragment of code, edit your question and I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: thank you very much, I will update my question soon with some of the code I am trying to write!